# Sharing the same mongodb database for a mac and a pc using Shard

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, sharding

I am currently working on an application that is built using MEAN (Mongo Express Angular Node) stack. Recently I have just built a PC and want to work on the project with both my PC at home and my MBP at work. All of my development work is tracked and constantly updated through git via github. So my question is:

- First: How do I do keep my database (Mongodb) updated between both my PC and my MBP?
- Second: Is Sharding the service I am looking to configure within my database in order to achieve what I want?
- Third: If so, how should I set up my database hosting servers, and shard servers? (Should I set up all my configsvr and one of my shard server files on my PC, and another shard server on my MBP?  (and connecting all via IP addresses:port)
- Fourth: Do all servers (shard & database/configsvr) need to be up and running for it to work, in another word if my pc is off, can I work on my project using my MBP and expect the data to be updated when the next time I use PC for development?)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Thanks @SeanMcSomthing First time posting a question, wasn't sure how to format it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean keeping you database synced with your Mac and PC, if so just create js migration scripts when you change the database schema or data then run them everytime the application starts up.

I've never really dev'd using a sharded cluster locally unless I'm trying to see what the execution plan would look like in certain scenarios or just generally playing around. I'd try to just run a single node for development and only cluster out when you put in to test/staging/live etc...

Comment: Yes! Exactly, I need to keep the database on my Mac and Pc in sync. What are some good documentations for mongodb migration, I have found mongodb-migrations, but it doesnt really go in depth of how my data can be synced with the web (like github repos for my html/css/js files). Also would it be a good idea to start doing a sharded cluster to have it ready for testing and production?

Comment: I've always just hand rolled some js files that add a document within a `migrations` collection with the date description and a unique id then check it each time you deploy and if it doesn't exist then run the migration on the database. pretty much the same as you do with any other database.

Comment: I ended up hosted my database with mlab, and everything syncs up really nicely now. Thanks for all the help.